# How to use buffer overflow exploit

Tags: c, fgets, buffer-overflow, exploit

I try to learn the buffer overflow exploit .

i have this code :

```
       #include <stdio.h>
       int read_req(FILE *p) {
       char buf[16];
       int i;
       fgets(buf, 1024, p);
       i = atoi(buf);
       return i;
      }
      int main() {
       FILE *fp = fopen("/home/assignment/shellcode", "r");
        int x = read_req(fp);
       printf("x = %d\n", x);
      }
```

I want to exploit this code using this  shellcode :

```
  #include <stdio.h>

  void main() {

   char *name[2];

   name[0] = "/bin/sh";

  name[1] = NULL;

   /* Launch shell */

   execve(name[0],name, NULL);

 }
```

but i dont know how  to use it ,  also  i heard that   fgets  dont cause the buffer overflow problem .. I'm confused

Think you

Comment: A buffer overflow occurs (generally) when an input is larger than the size of the buffer that it is meant to go in.  You can still have a buffer overflow with `fgets` - the reason `fgets` is usually recommended is because you the programmer get to designate exactly how big your input can be.  If you allow it to be larger than your buffer - congrats, buffer overflow even with `fgets`.  That said... most programmers (at least, most that I've met) tend to frown upon "exploits".  It's an easy way to enter a legal grey zone (if not full-on illegal activities).

Answer (score 0):

Place a few hundred 'A's in the file `/home/assignment/shellcode` and run the vulnerable application under the `gdb` debugger. This should overwrite eip/rip and be enough to get your started.